# Subgroup of Plane Isometries Isomorphic to $O_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry

Let $\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E})$ be the group of the isometries of the euclidean plane $\mathbf{E}$, and for every point $P \in \mathbf{E}$, let $\mathcal{Isom}_P$ be the subgroup of all isometries of $\mathbf{E}$ that fix $P$. It is well known that $\mathcal{Isom}_P \simeq O_2(\mathbb{R})$. Is the converse true? That is, if $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E})$, and $H \simeq O_2(\mathbb{R})$, is is true that there exists some point $P \in \mathbf{E}$ such that $H = \mathcal{Isom}_P$?

Even though it seems quite a reasonable statement, every attempt that I made to prove it has failed up to now, so any help is welcome in answering this question. Thank you very much in dvance for your kind attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H$ has a subgroup $K$ of index $2$ isomorphic to $SO_2$ and so commutative.
Then $K$ has an element $g$ of order $3$. The isometries of the plane of order $3$ are
rotations through angle $\pm2\pi/3$. So $g$ is a rotation centred at a some point $P$.
The centralizer of $g$ in the isometry group of the plane is the set of all
rotations with centre $P$. So $K\subseteq\text{Rotations}_P$

The elements of $H-K$ don't centralise $g$ but normalise the subgroup it generates.
The isometries which do this are the reflections fixing $P$. Therefore
$H$ is a subgroup of the stabiliser of $P$.

But there are proper subgroups of $O_2$ which are isomorphic to $O_2$
so we cannot say that $H$ is the stabiliser of $P$, but if say $H$
is a closed subgroup of the isometry group, then it is.

Comment: Dear @AnginaSeng, thank you very much for having answered my question: it is a very beautiful and quite unexpected result for me! I could fill in all the missing details of the proof. I would only like to ask you very humbly some reference for a proof of the two facts you quoted:  (I) that $O_2$ has some proper subgroup isomorphic to itself, and (II) that the only closed subgroup of $O_2$ isomorphic to $O_2$ is $O_2$ itself.

Comment: @MaurizioBarbato (i) It's the usual sort of Zorn's Lemma/Hamel basis sort of thing. (ii) the rotations of finite order are dense in $SO_2$.

Comment: Dear @AnginaSeng, I see your point for (ii), but I can't figure out exactly what you mean by "Zorn's Lemma/Hamel basis sort of thing" for (i). $O_2$ is not a vector space, so how could we proceed? Could you give me some more detail, please? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a separate answer, but simply a long comment to Angina Seng's answer which has the purpose of fill in the missing details.
First of all, let us recall Chasles classification theorem for plane isometries: an isometry of the plane is a translation, a rotation, a reflection or a glide reflection.

Now let $g \in K$ be an element of order 3. Since translations and glide reflections have infinite order, while reflections have order 2, $g$ must be a rotation around some point $P$, and since $g$ has order 3, $g$ must be a reflection of $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ or of $- \frac{2 \pi}{3}$.
Now consider the centralizer $\mathcal{C}(g)= \{ f \in \mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E}): gf = gf \}$. Clearly every rotation around $P$ belongs to  $\mathcal{C}(g)$.
Conversely, let $f \in \mathcal{C}(g)$, and let $f(P)=Q$. Then $(gf)(P)=g(f(P))=g(Q)$, while $(fg)(P)=f(g(P))=Q$. So $g(Q)=Q$, and since $g$ fixes only $P$, we must have $P=Q$, that is $f$ fixes $P$. So $f$ must be a rotation around $P$ or a reflection with respect to a straight line $r$ passing through $P$. In this latter case we would have (remember that if $s$ is a reflection with respect to a straight line passing through $P$ and  $r$ is a rotation around $P$ we have $rs=sr^{-1}$): $gf=fg^{-1} \neq fg$, since $g \neq g^{-1}$. So $f$ must be a rotation around $P$. We conclude that

**$\mathcal{C}(g)$ coincides with the set of all rotations through $P$**.

Since $K$ is abelian, we have $K \subset \mathcal{C}(g)$, and so $K$ is a subset of the set of all rotations around $P$.

Now consider $H \backslash K$. Since $H \simeq O_2$ and $K \simeq SO_2$, the elements of $H \backslash K$ correspond to those of $O_2 \backslash SO_2$, and so they have the same algebraic properties. In particular, if we denote by $G$ the subgroup generated by $g$ (that is $G=\{id, g, g^2 \}$), we have that each element $h \in H \backslash K$ satisfies the two properties:

(i) $h \in N(G)=\{ f \in \mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E}): fGf^{-1}=G \}$;

(ii) $h \notin \mathcal{C}(g)$.

Now, consider the set $N(G) \cap (\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E}) \backslash \mathcal{C}(g))$, and let $f \in N(G) \cap (\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E}) \backslash \mathcal{C}(g))$. Let $f(P)=Q$. Since $fgf^{-1} \in G$ and $fgf^{-1} \neq id$ (since the only conjugate of the identity is the identity itself), we must have $fgf^{-1}=g^2$. So $fgf^{-1}=g^2$ fixes only $P$. But we have $(fgf^{-1})(Q)=Q$, and we conclude that $P=Q$, that is $f$ fixes $P$, so $f$ is a rotation around $P$ or it is a reflection with respect to a straight line passing through $P$. But since $f \notin \mathcal{C}(g)$, the first case is not possible, and we conclude that $f$ must be a reflection with respect to a straight line passing through $P$. On the other hand, every reflection $f$ with respect to a straight line passing through $P$ is in $N(G) \cap (\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E}) \backslash \mathcal{C}(g))$. Indeed, as seen above $f \notin in \mathcal{C}(g)$, while, since we have $fgf^{-1}=g^{-1}=g^{2}$ and $fg^{2}f^{-1}=g^{-2}=g$, we have $f \in N(G)$.
We conclude that

**$N(G) \cap (\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E}) \backslash \mathcal{C}(g))$ is the set of all reflections with respect to straight lines passing through $P$**.

In particular $H \backslash K$ is a subset of the set all reflections with respect to straight lines passing through $P$.

**So $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{Isom}_P$.**

Now we shall prove that with the additional assumption that $H$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathcal{Isom}(\mathbf{E})$, then $H= \mathcal{Isom}_P$. First, let us note that if $r$ is an element of $K$ of order $m$, where $m$ is a positive integer, then $r$ is a rotation around $P$ of order $m$, so that the subgroup $\langle r \rangle$ of $H$ generated by $r$ coincides with the subgroup  $\langle s \rangle$ of $\mathcal{Isom}_P$ generated by the rotation $s$ of $\frac{2 \pi}{m}$. So the set
\begin{equation}
S= \{ r \in K : \text{r has finite order} \},
\end{equation}
is dense in the subgroup $\mathcal{Rot}_P$ of all rotations around $P$. On the other hand, since for any reflection $\rho$ with respect to a straight line $r$ passing through $P$, and any rotation $R \in \mathcal{Rot}_P$ of angle $\theta$, $R \rho$ is the reflection with respect to the straight line $s$ passing through $P$ and rotated by an angle $\theta/2$ with respect to $r$, we see that, chosen any element $\rho \in H \backslash K$, the subset of $H$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\rho S = \{ \rho R : R \in S \},
\end{equation}
is dense in $\mathcal{Isom}_P \backslash \mathcal{Rot}_P$. We conclude then that $H$ is dense in $\mathcal{Isom}_P$, and so $H= \mathcal{Isom}_P$.

The final issue to settle is to show that, without any topological hypothesis on $H$, we can have that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathcal{Isom}_P$, which is equivalent to say that $O_2(\mathbb{R})$ admits some proper subgroup which is isomorphic to $O_2(\mathbb{R})$ itself. This has been proved by tomasz in his very beautiful answer to my post [Proper Subgroup of $O_2(\mathbb{R})$ Isomorphic to $O_2(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774909/proper-subgroup-of-o-2-mathbbr-isomorphic-to-o-2-mathbbr/3775604?noredirect=1#comment7777421_3775604).