Unital ring homomorphism
Let $f:K \rightarrow K$ be a unital ring homomorphism ,i.e.it is a ring homomorphism which sends unity to unity.
Here K is some field.
Then clearly it is injective as $\ker(f) =\{ 0 \}$.
I want to ask whether this is surjective also? Here $K$ is a field.
If we take $K=R$, then what happens?
(2).Another question I wanted to ask that is $Fp$ adjoined uncountable many variables is a field with positive characteristic and uncountable cardinality?
Any help will be grateful. Thank you.

"The clearly it injective, as $\ker f=0$." Are you claiming that every unital ring homomorphism is injective? That is not true.

"If we take $K=R$"... what is $R$? Is it supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$?  If $Fp$ supposed to be $\mathbb{F}_p$, the finite field of $p$ elements? When you say "adjoin", are you taking the polynomial ring, or its field of fractions? This needs clarity, and focus. Ask one question at a time, and make clear what you mean.

It is surjective for $\mathbb{R}$, it does not have to be in general, for example $\mathbb{C}$.

Consider $f: \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ defined by $f(x, y)= x$.  Then $f(1, 1)=1$ but $f$ clearly is not injective.

R denote field of real numbers and Fp finite field of order p.

@freakish,can you give me some example?

@DerwalMeena read this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110689/proper-subfields-of-mathbbc-isomorphic-to-mathbbc

Please only ask one question per post.
